# Get dates between two months

Tags: oracle-11g

Can I know why am I getting weird output in my SQL statement whereby my table has two dates of the month May but it only appears for one month, the same things I test for dates range it is working.

```
    select distinct To_Char (attendance_date,'dd/MM/yyyy') 
    from DIT_2010MAR_CIT4114A_FYP1_NO
    where attendance_Date between To_Date ('05', 'MM') and 
    To_Date ('05', 'MM');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your query doesn't return anything in my test :(. The reason is the `attendance_date` doesn't fall in between the condition that you have specified(`To_date('05','MM')` and 
 `To_date('05','MM')` is returning the same value).

You can change your code as 
  `...where attendance_date between To_date('05','MM') and To_date('06','MM');` to select all the dates of the May month.

```
SQL> desc atten;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ATTENDANCE_DATE                    DATE

SQL> select * from atten;

ATTENDANC
---------
05-MAY-16
03-JUN-16
03-JUL-16
03-MAY-16

SQL> select distinct To_Char (attendance_date,'dd/MM/yyyy') from atten where attendance_Date between To_Date ('05', 'MM') and To_Date ('05', 'MM');

no rows selected
```

You can try the following to get the result.

```
SQL> select to_char(attendance_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') from atten
where extract(month from attendance_date) = 5;  2  

TO_CHAR(AT
----------
05/05/2016
03/05/2016
```

OR If you wish to display attendance date of months between 5 and 6(As you question's title suggests).

```
select to_char(attendance_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') from atten
where extract(month from attendance_date) = 5 OR extract(month from attendance_date)=6;
TO_CHAR(AT
----------
05/05/2016
03/06/2016
03/05/2016
```

Comment: thanks, sql developer giving weird i did not tey using sqlplus. If sql developer it appears 01-May-2016 eventhough this not in the table values

Comment: can i know when i use my codes for dates working why for month it is not working but youyr code working?